# How to access GitHub through SVN (Dreamweaver CS6)

Tags: svn, github, dreamweaver

So I am relatively new to GitHub and am trying to use it with an open source team to develop a simple web application. Upon committing a file I am prompted with an error saying "Files must be stored under trunk/ or branches/ subdirectory."

Is there a way I can append my GitHub URL to only access the trunk? Currently my settings are the following in Dreamweaver CS6...

Server Address: github.com

Repository Path: /username/RepoName.git

Server Port: 443

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Git and Subversion use different URLs for accessing repository
2. You **must** checkout the whole repository from Github before you start to work
3. You have to use right URL for repository

> Is there a way I can append my GitHub URL to only access the trunk?

No. Git-URLs are not path-based, single repo under the same URL have **all branches**

Additional reading:

- [Improved Subversion Client Support](https://github.com/blog/966-improved-subversion-client-support)
- [Collaborating on GitHub with Subversion](https://github.com/blog/1178-collaborating-on-github-with-subversion)

When I used hints from the first article, I checkouted my Git-repo from Github by svn client. For `https://github.com/lazybadger/Fiver-l10n.git` Git-repo

`svn co https://github.com/lazybadger/Fiver-l10n`

checkout the whole repository-tree

```
>dir /B /S /AD
z:\Fiver-l10n
z:\Fiver-l10n\.svn
z:\Fiver-l10n\branches
z:\Fiver-l10n\trunk
```